# User count in a day with 30minutes time interval oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I want logged in  users count with 30minutes time interval.

**There are total 48 intervals.** If a user is logged into the database then his/her start_time (login in ) and end_time (logout time), userid will be recorded into the table
a user can be logged in more than one time period. I'm taking 2017-jul-12 data 
**For ex:**  user with id 2 is logged in 2 times and so the value of the count for that user will be 2 (at 12:02 to 12:07 and 11:46pm to 11:51pm)  similarly if a user logged in into a time period and logged out into other time period than the count will be treated for both the interval i.e. 2
For ex: user with id 3...

**Input**

```
user                   start_date                         end_time
1       12-JUL-17 12.02.09.430000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.02.13.310000000 AM
2       12-JUL-17 12.02.13.323000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.07.33.343000000 AM
3       12-JUL-17 12.06.19.203000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.37.49.890000000 AM
4       12-JUL-17 12.07.33.357000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.07.37.813000000 AM
5       12-JUL-17 12.07.37.813000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.07.40.690000000 AM
6       12-JUL-17 12.07.40.707000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.12.58.470000000 AM
7       12-JUL-17 12.12.58.487000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.13.01.937000000 AM
8       12-JUL-17 12.13.01.950000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.18.22.193000000 AM
9       12-JUL-17 12.13.20.267000000 AM     12-JUL-17 12.45.38.013000000 AM
2       12-JUL-17 11.46.17.827000000 PM     12-JUL-17 11.51.32.267000000 PM
3       12-JUL-17 11.47.03.497000000 PM     13-JUL-17 12.20.17.167000000 AM
```

**Output**

```
count(id)       interval
   9                1
   2                2
   0                47   
   2                48
```

**There are total 48 intervals(30minutes each)**

```
count(id)       interval
   9                1 (12 - 12:30 am)
   2                2 (12:30 - 1:00 am)
   .                 .
   .                 .
   .               47 (11:00 - 11:30 pm)
   2               48 (11:30 - 12:00 am)
```

**Query**

```
With Periods as
(
select to_timestamp(:TheDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') + (level-1)/48 as p_start, to_timestamp(:TheDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')  + (level)/48 as p_end, level as p_id
from dual connect by level<=48
)
select p.*, count(distinct t1.id) as distinct_users
from Periods p
left join Input t1
on t1.start_date < p_end
and t1.end_date >= p_start
group by p.p_id, p.p_start, p.p_end
```

I already played with this  query but it does not giving me a accurate answer
**Note**: both the date columns are in timestamp

**Query hint given by:**https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144048/johnhc

Comment: What is the accurate answer that you expect?

Comment: Question about the "boundary issue" that always arises in such problems. Suppose a user logged in at 10:00 and logged out at 10:30 sharp. Was this user "logged in" for the interval from 9:30 to 10:00? Was she "logged in" for the interval from 10:30 to 11:00? If not, you must specify EXACTLY how each of the possible boundary conditions must be handled.

Comment: @wolfrevokcats  thankx fr showing your interest ...i already displayed the output you can see i just want users count with in the 48 intervals

Comment: @mathguy  that&#39;s a Good question .. First let me  figure it out by looking into my  whole data then i&#39;ll tell you !!

Comment: hey @mathguy, If user logged in at (10:00 - 10:30) then he/she will be come into the 10 - 10:30 interval AND 10:30 -11:00 to  with COUNT 2 if 
user logged in at 10:00 - 10:29:59 then he/she will be come into only one interval i.e. (10 - 10:30).
 but lets suppose a user logged in at 10:00 and logged out at 10:31 then he/she will be come under 2 intervals (10 - 10:30 and 10:30 - 11:00) because user was logged in into the interval(10:30 - 11:00) for 1 minutes and that will be counted. hope you will understand!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would to this with a join against ALL_OBJECTS WHERE rownum<=48 to represent the different intervals. Then you join it against your periods table and group it by user.

```
SELECT intervals.interval, COUNT(DISTINCT "USER") FROM (SELECT rownum AS interval FROM all_objects WHERE rownum <= 48) intervals
LEFT OUTER JOIN test2 ON intervals.interval BETWEEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM start_date) * 2 + FLOOR(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM start_date)/30) + 1
                                                AND CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM start_date) != EXTRACT(DAY FROM end_time) THEN 48 ELSE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM end_time) * 2 + FLOOR(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM end_time)/30) + 1 END 
GROUP BY intervals.interval
ORDER BY intervals.interval
```